# Python Remove Spanish Words

Tags: python

I have a list of tokens such as `["Adiós", "John", "Salud", "Love"]` and my task is to delete the word if it is recognized as Spanish.

I have tried `enchant` and `polyglot` but they just cannot connect to `aspell`.

Are there any other easier modules or methods to detect Spanish words and delete them?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe delete if it is not English?

Comment: You could try [this](https://github.com/detectlanguage/detectlanguage-python), it's a Python client from the [Language Detection API](https://detectlanguage.com/).

Comment: `langdetect` is usually pretty good for sentences, but not individual words. For example, `langdetect.detect('John')` returns `de`, not `en`

Comment: @stark I have tried but it's too "strong" to keep words like "Obamacare."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [language-detector](https://github.com/DanielJDufour/language-detector). You could try that.

```
from language_detector import detect_language

data = ["Adiós", "John", "Salud", "Love"]

not_spanish_data = [word for word in data if detect_language(word) != 'Spanish']

print(not_spanish_data)
#['John', "Salud" 'Love']
```

Comment: Let me try it and I will report how this works, thanks!

Comment: Tested, it does detect "Obamacare" as English, I'm not great with spanish, but it does detect "Salud" as French, so if that's what you want is just no Spanish then this should work

Comment: I don't know why I was downvoted though, this seems like a perfectly viable answer although with a broader dataset you will need to test.

Comment: I didn't downgrade it and it works as you described. I just upgraded it.

Comment: @tzu does this answer your question?